# Sqoop: command not found

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 with Hadoop 1.0.3. I recently downloaded sqoop manually and gave the path in /etc/environment. But my terminal say 'sqoop: command not found'. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Why did you download it manually instead using for example Cloudera repo?

Answer (score 2):

execute `echo $PATH` to see the directories in which Linux searches for executed binaries. You should see the `bin` sub-directory of your sqoop installation folder in this path. For example, if you've installed to `/usr/local/sqoop`, your path should contain `/usr/local/sqoop/bin`.

If you do not see this setting, change it wherever you have your `$PATH` configured, e.g. in .bash_profile if you're using bash.

Answer (score 0):

if you are installing sqoop, normally executables are found in /sqoop/bin/ directory.
could you please check ,if the path specified is correct.
you could also try the absolute path  bin/sqoop

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these entries in added in ~/.bashrc file

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_71"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

export SQOOP_HOME="/home/abhisr/sqoop-1.99.5-bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin"